# Why didn't the publisher advertise "The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes" more heavily?

Tags: publishing, suzanne-collins, the-ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes

Suzanne Collins recently released *The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes* rather abruptly, without much advertising or announcement, during the middle of the COVID-19 pandemic (May 19, 2020). I follow the series fairly closely, and I didn't realize that it had been released until nearly a month later. I was not able to find it on the June 21 or May 31 editions of the *New York Times* bestseller list, and I do not recall seeing it before (unless I missed something). (Admittedly, though, it stands at #10 on Amazon.com as of 6/24/2020).

Am I mistaken, or has the publisher done very little advertising of this and offer no advanced notice of its publication? If so, why did they do this?

Comment: And yet https://www.booksandpublishing.com.au/articles/2020/06/09/151630/bestsellers-second-week-at-number-one-for-the-ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes/ said "The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes is spending its second consecutive week in the top spot on the Australian bestsellers chart following its number-one debut last week." Whatever they did in Australia seems to be plenty sufficient.

Comment: @muru Australian bestseller list? That seems like a consolation prize.

Comment: Maybe, but it indicates enough people knew about it even in the backwaters.